# нужен бесплатный хостинг для экспериментов. Загружать, выгружать сайты . Чтобы было 3-5 бесплатных домена и хостинга

Tags: хостинг, домен

Мне нужен бесплатный хостинг для экспериментов. Загружать, выгружать сайты . Чтобы было 3-5 бесплатных домена и хостинга

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте Heroku, удобная инфраструктура, множество плагинов, интеграция с популярными сервисами CI и развертка через Docket. Бесплатно разрешают поднимать единовременно 5 приложений, дальше просят платить. На бесплатной подписке сервер с приложением работает не больше 16 часов в день. Для тестовых целей должно хватить